# RxJS6 Observable of array with add/remove subjects

Tags: rxjs6

Let's say I want to have:

- an observable of numbers `numbers$`;
- a subject `addNumber$`;
- a subject `removeNumber$`;

I want to create `numbers$` which works like this:

|  | `numbers$.subscribe()` |
| --- | --- |
| `addNumber$.next(10)` | `[10]` |
| `addNumber$.next(20)` | `[10, 20]` |
| `removeNumber$.next(10)` | `[20]` |
| `addNumber$.next(30)` | `[20, 30]` |
| `addNumber$.next(40)` | `[20, 30, 40]` |

Any ideas? Is it possible to avoid backing field for storing array of numbers?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to have state without using state?

Comment: @Enigmativity No I'm not asking this, I ask how to implement `numbers$` the best way.

Comment: So, help me to understand what you're asking. Are you saying that, if you execute each statement on the left, then, if at the moment in time you subscribe, you get the output on the right?

Comment: @Enigmativity. Exactly — `numbers$` emits the arrays like in the example.